# passing a clob to JSon_object_t

Tags: oracle, plsql, base64, blob

How do i pass a {Base64 encoded content} value in a json object. the file that i want to send is a blob type in my Oracle Table.

FOLLOWING snippets of my code

```sql
Cursor csr_con_attach is 
      select file_name documentName,file_blob ,
             to_char(created_date,'DD-MON-YYYY')||'T'||to_char(created_date,'HH24:MI:SS') documentDate 
                             From contact.con_attachments
                WHERE con_header_id_fk = 2770;
e.g.

 For rec_con_attach in csr_con_attach
 Loop
   v_obj_build :=
   json_object_t 
       ('{' 
           || '"documentName"' || ':"' || rec_con_attach.documentName  || '",'
           || '"blobData"'     || ':"' || rec_con_attach.file-blob ||'",' 
           || '"documentNotes"'     || ':"' || 'Test' ||'",' 
           || '"documentDate"'     || ':"' || rec_con_attach.documentDate 
           ||'"'|| 
         '}');
end loop;
```

When i compile this I get an error "wrong number or type of arguments in call to '||" . The rest API that i am calling expects a  {Base64 encoded content} for blobData.

I also tried converting blob file to base64encode(using procedure below), but then i get JSONT syntax error ORA-06512 sys.JDOM_T

```sql
Declare
  l_step         pls_integer := 22500; -- make sure you set a multiple of 3 not higher  than 24573
  l_clob         clob;
begin

 for i in 0 .. trunc((dbms_lob.getlength(i_blob) - 1 )/l_step) 
  loop
   dbms_output.put_line(i);
   l_clob := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(dbms_lob.substr(i_blob, l_step, i * l_step + 1)));


end loop;
 io_clob := l_clob;

end;
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Is this PLSql? You can get more answer if you add a code language tag to your question.

Comment: i am doing using the procedure (in my post), but then it gives me JSONT syntax error ORA-06512 sys.JDOM_T

Comment: Is the typo `file-blob` in your actual code? (instead of `file_blob`)

Comment: sorry it is a typo, it is a column in my table and it should be file_blob